# How to obtain name of another sheet based on a cell value in current sheet?

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

For example, I have a date column in current sheet (overview_sheet) and a count column, the sheets are named the same with the addition of a date behind it to differentiate each sheet eg. `sheet_0714`, `sheet_0715`

For the count column cells, I use functions like `=sheet_0715!H20` manually to get the value from the other sheet, but is there a way where I can change the date part of the function dynamically based on the date of the row?

so, `=sheet_(date)!H20` where (date) is based on date of the row in current sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use one of the following, depending on how your cells are formatted.

1. formatted as text: _0715
   `=INDIRECT("sheet"&T1&"!H20")`
2. formatted as date: 0715
   `=INDIRECT("sheet_"&TEXT(T2,"mmdd")&"!H20")`

[image]

Functions used:

- [`INDIRECT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377)
- [`TEXT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139)